# How to create a dynamic where clause using a name value collection?

Tags: linq, dynamic, where-clause, namevaluecollection

I have column search filter values sent to my web api and I can't figure how to make the where clause dynamic?

> Look below (too much code)!!

**Name Value Collection:**

```
  public DataTablePager<AccountDTO> Get([FromUri] DataTableParameter param)
        {
            NameValueCollection nvc = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.RequestUri.Query);
```

**Casting the search values:**

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["sSearch_0"]) && !int.TryParse(nvc["sSearch_0"], out tmpInt) ||
                !String.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["sSearch_1"]) && !int.TryParse(nvc["sSearch_1"], out tmpInt) ||
                !String.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["sSearch_10"]) && !int.TryParse(nvc["sSearch_10"], out tmpInt)
```

**Setup Where Clause:**

```
filteredresults = filteredresults.Where(i => CorrectNumericTypes
                                                      && (Lead_ID == null || i.Lead_ID == Lead_ID)
                                                      && (Account_ID == null || i.Account_ID == Account_ID)
```

Comment: Use a predicate builder. There are many questions (and answers) about dynamically building predicates.

Comment: Predicate is what I needed, Thank you Arnold. Wish I could give you points!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I needed (predicate): http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/c42694/dynamic-query-in-linq-using-predicate-builder/

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic case for the [**Pipes and Filters** Architectural pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn568100.aspx).
You can construct a list of filters based on dynamic (runtime) conditions. Or keep a static list of filters, the ones where there is no criteria, the data just passes through. Apply this list of filters on the data set or the Query.

I don't think you can achieve that with LINQ. You can design a query builder (using the same Filters pattern)